# VLC ActiveX plugin Media Play Event

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I am working on VLC ActiveX plugin in windows form application. I am loading RTSP stream from a source in VLC. I want to know that which event i should register to check that RTSP stream is loaded and starts playing. I have implemented some events but they get fired before stream is loaded.

```
MediaPlayerPlaying
MediaPlayerBuffering
MediaPlayerForward.
```

Any help?